# Facebook.Client package installing error

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio, sdk, nuget

I am trying to install Facebook.Client package in my Visual Studio project, but it failed with this message:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Facebook.Client 1.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Facebook.Client` is for Windows Store and Windows Phone apps. From the [readme](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk/blob/master/README.md):

> The Facebook C# SDK for Windows & Windows Phone helps .NET developers build Windows Phone and Windows Store applications that integrate with Facebook.

Since your project targets .NET Framework 4.5, I'm assuming that you're building a desktop or ASP.NET app. What you're looking for is the [Facebook C# SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/).